# ClientInterceptor and Firebase IdToken

Tags: java, android, firebase-authentication, interceptor

I am usign GRPC service and I am trying to extends ClientInterceptor to append some headers and ask to Firebase to give me a IdToken but I don't understand how can do it because `task.getResult()` go to in exception `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Task is not yet complete`

I have tried also with a sync mode
`GetTokenResult tokenResult = Tasks.await(task, 20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`
but nothing, exception `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Must not be called on the main application thread`

```
public class CustomHeaderInterceptor implements ClientInterceptor {
    @Override
    public <ReqT, RespT> ClientCall<ReqT, RespT> interceptCall(MethodDescriptor<ReqT, RespT> method, CallOptions callOptions, Channel next) {
        return new ForwardingClientCall.SimpleForwardingClientCall<ReqT, RespT>(next.newCall(method, callOptions)) {
            @Override
            public void start(Listener<RespT> responseListener, Metadata headers) {
                headers.put(Metadata.Key.of("X-XXX", Metadata.ASCII_STRING_MARSHALLER), "test_test");

                try {
                    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                    if (user == null) {
                        throw new Exception("User is not logged in.");
                    } else {
                        Task<GetTokenResult> task = user.getIdToken(false);
                        GetTokenResult tokenResult = task.getResult();

                        String idToken = tokenResult.getToken();
                        headers.put(Metadata.Key.of("Authorization", Metadata.ASCII_STRING_MARSHALLER), "Bearer " + idToken);

                        super.start(responseListener, headers);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), new Gson().toJson(e));
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

I have tried also `CompletableFuture`

```
                        Task<GetTokenResult> task = user.getIdToken(false);
                        CompletableFuture<String> completableFuture = new CompletableFuture<>();
                        task.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<>() {
                           @Override
                            public void onComplete(Task<GetTokenResult> task1) {
                                GetTokenResult tokenResult = task1.getResult();
                                String idToken = tokenResult.getToken();
                                completableFuture.complete(idToken);
                           }
                        });
                        String idToken = completableFuture.get();
```

but the code stop on `completableFuture.get()`

How can I do to ask and append on each call the firebase token?

Comment: For posterity: this is discussed in more detail a grpc-java [issue](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/10608).